# Find $\min$ for$ f(x) = (x + a + b)(x + a - b)(x - a + b)(x - a - b)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, optimization, maxima-minima

I'm trying to find $minf(x)$ for $f(x) := (x + a + b)(x + a - b)(x - a + b)(x - a - b)$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R},$ using inequalities. 
For example, i can find $maxf(x)$, using **AM-GM** ineq:
$$\sqrt[4]{(x + a + b)(x + a - b)(x - a + b)(x - a - b)})^4 \leq \Big (\frac{x + a + b + x + a - b+ x - a + b+ x - a - b}{4}\Big)^4 = $$
$$= x^4.$$
So $maxf(x) = x^4$.
But i don't know how to solve is for $minf(x)$, which i need to find.

Sure do i can find structure of *square difference* in $f(x)$ and we can rewrite our equality: 
$$f(x) = (x^2 - (a + b)^2) (x^2 - (b - a)^2).$$
But i don't know what to do next.

**UPD:** We need to find extremum on $x$ via fixing $a, b$. I understand that $max$ is found wrong way. How can i do it correctly?

Comment: for a fixed nonzero $x,$ there is no minimum and no maximum. With $x \neq 0,$ first take $a=b=t$ for some real $t.$ This gives $-4x^2 t^2 + x^4,$ no lower bound as $t$ varies. Second, take $a=t, b=0,$ this gives $t^4 - 2 x^2 t^2,$ no upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=(x^2-(a^2+b^2))^2+(b^2-a^2)^2-(a^2+b^2)^2\ge(b^2-a^2)^2-(a^2+b^2)^2=-4a^2b^2$$
The equality occurs for $x^2=a^2+b^2$, which is always possible.

Comment: I think the OP wants to fix $x$ and minimize on $a,b$ (as he does for the maximization). You're doing the opposite

Comment: for a fixed nonzero $x,$ there is no minimum and no maximum. With $x \neq 0,$ first take $a=b=t$ for some real $t.$ This gives $-4x^2 t^2 + x^4,$ no lower bound as $t$ varies. Second, take $a=t, b=0,$ this gives $t^4 - 2 x^2 t^2,$ no upper bound.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, correct me if i wrong, but we take x = $\pm \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ - this way we fixed it. Then we finding minimum on $a, b$

Comment: @WillJagy You're right. The question seems ill-posed

Comment: @Juicer When you take $x=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ yoyu get $f=-4a^2b^2$ which still depends on $a$ and $b$, so you have not yet the minimum in $a,b$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy well then it is my fault since i must to to tell initial conditions right. And i told it wrong cause i misunderstood exercise by myself. What i need is to fix $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and find extremum on $x$. Can you tell me how can i find $max$ with this conditions?

Comment: @Juicer Everything is said and explained in WillJagy's answer

Comment: @EwanDelanoy and again, you misunderstood me. We don't need to replace $a, b$ for real values, it is some constants. We need to find solution, containing $a, b$.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed nonzero $x,$ there is no minimum and no maximum.

To exceed any upper bound, take $a = t$ and $b=0$ for some large $t.$ The original polynomial becomes $t^4 - 2 x^2 t^2 = t^2 (t^2 - 2 x^2) \; . \;$ As soon as $t^2 > 2 x^2 + 1,$ the polynomial is larger than $t^2,$ and we may take $t$ as large as we like. In particular, if $t^2 > 3 x^2,$ the value is bigger than $3 x^4$

For negative, take $a=b=t,$ gives $-4x^2 t^2 + x^4.$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

Denote $t=a+b$ and $s=a-b$, then $f(x)$ becomes to be $(x^2-t^2)(x^2-s^2)$. Henece $f(x)$ is quintic which is very easy to work with, more specifically,
$$f(x)=x^4-(s^2+t^2)x^2+t^2s^2.$$
Now, you can make another substitution, namely $y=x^2$ to obtain a quadratic, which you know how to find a minimum of it. Don't forget to returnt to given variables.

Comment: it is not a quintic polynomial. It is just a quartic polynomial (or biquadratic you can say).

Comment: @Martund, thank you very much for this information.

Comment: for a fixed nonzero $x,$ there is no minimum and no maximum. With $x \neq 0,$ first take $a=b=t$ for some real $t.$ This gives $-4x^2 t^2 + x^4,$ no lower bound as $t$ varies. Second, take $a=t, b=0,$ this gives $t^4 - 2 x^2 t^2,$ no upper bound.